# Android AdWhirl: Ads not getting displayed

Tags: android, adwhirl

I really having trouble in displaying Ads through AdWhirl.

Following is the code:

```
AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(true);
AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseAppName(APP_NAME);
AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseCompanyName(COMPANY_NAME);
final DisplayMetrics dm = showComments.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = new AdWhirlLayout(showComments,    
                                        MyWidgetProvider.ADWHIRL_SDK_KEY);
adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (dm.density * 320));
adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (dm.density * 52));
adWhirlLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
//LayoutInflater inflater=showComments.getLayoutInflater();
View header=inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_layout, null);
FrameLayout ad_frame=(FrameLayout)header.findViewById(R.id.ad_frame);
ad_frame.addView(adWhirlLayout);

showComments.getListView().addHeaderView(ad_frame);
```

But Ad never get display. I have set up the SDK key for `AdWhirl, AdMob and InMobi`. I also have `INTERNET permissions`. I set up all the the keys one day before. I am calling this in main UI thread. And **I am testing this on emulator with test mode set to TRUE**.

Following is the LogCat:

```
04-15 19:46:20.667: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(473): Creating adWhirlManager...
04-15 19:46:20.667: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Locale is: en_US
04-15 19:46:20.707: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Hashed device ID is: 7d1dd13a2fa91c0ad174cb69a11549a3
04-15 19:46:20.707: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(473): Finished creating adWhirlManager
04-15 19:46:20.777: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Prefs{3f3895c9b2924d01ad2af284f82b9e5e}: {"config": "{"extra":{"location_on":0,"background_color_rgb":{"red":59,"green":89,"blue":152,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":300,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"2eae10658d78483aaf55fcd8d08e7401","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":50,"priority":1,"key":"a14da6925c1450f"},{"nid":"00fb2956c3a34215abdbcde851c71d15","type":18,"nname":"inmobi","weight":50,"priority":2,"key":"4028cba62f1f1e04012f52d9bf990229"}]}
04-15 19:46:20.777: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): ", "timestamp": 1302876570581}
04-15 19:46:20.796: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(473): Using stored config data
04-15 19:46:20.796: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Received jsonString: {"extra":{"location_on":0,"background_color_rgb":{"red":59,"green":89,"blue":152,"alpha":1},"text_color_rgb":{"red":255,"green":255,"blue":255,"alpha":1},"cycle_time":300,"transition":8},"rations":[{"nid":"2eae10658d78483aaf55fcd8d08e7401","type":1,"nname":"admob","weight":50,"priority":1,"key":"a14da6925c1450f"},{"nid":"00fb2956c3a34215abdbcde851c71d15","type":18,"nname":"inmobi","weight":50,"priority":2,"key":"4028cba62f1f1e04012f52d9bf990229"}]}
04-15 19:46:20.837: INFO/AdWhirl SDK(473): Rotating Ad
04-15 19:46:20.857: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Dart is <92.86105004071> of <100.0>
04-15 19:46:20.898: INFO/System.out(473): In AttachmentView1==>
04-15 19:46:21.427: INFO/System.out(473): In NormalView1==>
04-15 19:46:21.767: DEBUG/dalvikvm(473): GC_CONCURRENT freed 537K, 51% free 3097K/6279K, external 955K/1463K, paused 12ms+38ms
04-15 19:46:21.818: DEBUG/dalvikvm(63): GC_CONCURRENT freed 855K, 46% free 4393K/8071K, external 1879K/2377K, paused 13ms+35ms
04-15 19:46:21.947: DEBUG/webviewglue(473): nativeDestroy view: 0x30ab30
04-15 19:46:21.977: DEBUG/webviewglue(473): nativeDestroy view: 0x251658
04-15 19:46:22.006: DEBUG/webviewglue(473): nativeDestroy view: 0x3075a8
04-15 19:46:22.019: DEBUG/webviewglue(473): nativeDestroy view: 0x276d50
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Showing ad:
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     nid: 00fb2956c3a34215abdbcde851c71d15
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     name: inmobi
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     type: 18
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     key: 4028cba62f1f1e04012f52d9bf990229
04-15 19:46:22.057: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     key2: 
04-15 19:46:22.086: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Valid adapter, calling handle()
04-15 19:46:22.317: VERBOSE/(473): in ad request post body..
04-15 19:46:22.358: VERBOSE/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): requestactivity=AdRequest&d-    deviceModel=sdk&d-deviceMachineHW=Linux%28Android%3A2.6.29-00261-g0097074-dirty%29&d-deviceSystemName=BASE&d-deviceSystemVersion=1.0&d-deviceName=generic&d-deviceBTHW=Fri+Apr+15+19%3A27%3A43+GMT%2B05%3A30+2011&d-deviceStorageSize=InBuilt%3A64+MB%2CExt%3A98+MB&d-device-screen-density=1.0&d-device-screen-size=320X480&x-inmobi-phone-useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.3%3B+en-us%3B+sdk+Build%2FGRH55%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F533.1&mk-siteid=4028cba62f1f1e04012f52d9bf990229&u-id=&mk-version=pr-SPEC-ATATA-20091223&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=InMobi_androidsdk%3D2.0&u-InMobi_androidwebsdkVersion=2.0&u-appBId=com.mobisys.android.app_widget&u-appDNM=FBDroidWidget&u-appVer=1.0&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=&mk-banner-size=9
04-15 19:46:22.407: WARN/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): requestactivity=AdRequest&d-deviceModel=sdk&d-deviceMachineHW=Linux%28Android%3A2.6.29-00261-g0097074-dirty%29&d-deviceSystemName=BASE&d-deviceSystemVersion=1.0&d-deviceName=generic&d-deviceBTHW=Fri+Apr+15+19%3A27%3A43+GMT%2B05%3A30+2011&d-deviceStorageSize=InBuilt%3A64+MB%2CExt%3A98+MB&d-device-screen-density=1.0&d-device-screen-size=320X480&x-inmobi-phone-useragent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+2.3%3B+en-us%3B+sdk+Build%2FGRH55%29+AppleWebKit%2F533.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F533.1&mk-siteid=4028cba62f1f1e04012f52d9bf990229&u-id=&mk-version=pr-SPEC-ATATA-20091223&format=xhtml&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=InMobi_androidsdk%3D2.0&u-InMobi_androidwebsdkVersion=2.0&u-appBId=com.mobisys.android.app_widget&u-appDNM=FBDroidWidget&u-appVer=1.0&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=&mk-banner-size=9
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): Exception retrieving ad
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.ConnectionException: Error requesting new Ad 
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.retrieveAd(RequestResponseManager.java:197)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.requestAd(RequestResponseManager.java:54)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView.fetchAndDisplayAd(InMobiAdView.java:206)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView.access$4(InMobiAdView.java:179)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView$3.call(InMobiAdView.java:292)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView$3.call(InMobiAdView.java:1)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.BackgroundWorker$1.run(BackgroundWorker.java:36)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://w.sandbox.mkhoj.com/showad.asm
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:519)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     at com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.net.RequestResponseManager.retrieveAd(RequestResponseManager.java:157)
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473):     ... 12 more
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): InMobi failure
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Showing ad:
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     nid: 2eae10658d78483aaf55fcd8d08e7401
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     name: admob
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     type: 1
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     key: a14da6925c1450f
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473):     key2: 
04-15 19:46:23.437: DEBUG/AdWhirl SDK(473): Valid adapter, calling handle()
```

As you can see, it throws the following exception:

```
04-15 19:46:22.906: ERROR/inmobiandroidwebsdk(473): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://w.sandbox.mkhoj.com/showad.asm
```

Anyone had this problem before? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.